# jQuery UI Position - Selector for parent element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, parent

I want to use jQuery UI's position utility to center a number of elements with the same class inside of their respective parent elements. Here's what I came up with:

```
$(".elementclass").position({
    "my": "center center",
    "at": "center center",
    "of": $(this).parent()
});
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, since the jQuery object $(this) somehow does not refer to the positioned element in this context. How can I pull this off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
$(".elementclass").each(function(i)
{
   $(this).position({
    "my": "center center",
    "at": "center center",
    "of": $(this).parent()
   });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, can't accept your answer yet b/c of stupid SOF limitation.

Answer (score 2):

You could put it inside an "each" function like this:

```
$(".elementclass").each(function() {
    $(this).position({
        "my": "center center",
        "at": "center center",
        "of": $(this).parent()
    });
});
```

This would loop through each element with the class of "elementclass", and position each item individually. Because you're referencing each element inside the function, $(this) will refer to the element you're trying to position.

Comment: Thank you to you, too. Works perfectly.